# ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned

Tags: python, pandas

I have four data frames that are importing data from different excel files ( Suppliers) and I am trying to combine these frames. When I include df3 when concatenating I get an error. I referred a lot of articles on similar error but not getting clue.

I tried upgrading pandas.
Tried the following code as well
                                                Data = DataFrame([df1,df2,df3,df4],columns= 'Supplier','Entity','Address','Site','State','Waste Description','Quantity','UOM','Disposal Facility','Disposal Cost','Trans Cost'])

```
  df1 = data1[['Supplier','Entity','Address','Site','State','Waste Description','Quantity','UOM','Disposal Facility']]   
  Shape: (3377, 9) 

  df2 = data2[['Supplier','Entity','Address','Site','State','Waste Description','Quantity','UOM','unit price','Invoice Total','Disposal Facility']]
  Shape:(13838, 11)

  df3 = data3[['Supplier','Entity','Address','Site','State','Waste Description','Quantity','UOM','Disposal Facility']]  
  Shape:(1185, 10)

  df4 = data4[['Supplier','Entity','Address','Site','State','Waste Description','Quantity','UOM','Disposal Facility','Disposal Cost','Trans Cost']]    
  Shape: (76, 11)

 data = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
 data1 = pd.concat(data)   

 ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned
```

When I remove df3 the data gets combined. I read that number of columns between dataframe doesn't matter.

Comment: looks like `df3` has duplicate column names (you've selected 9 column labels but are getting back 10 total columns according to the shape)

Comment: This is strange. "Quanity" in df3 is causing the issue. Thanks for pointing out but don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after entering the following code

data3['Quantity'] = data3['Quantity'].replace(" ","")